# VPN into another LAN without public IP over server with public IP

Tags: vpn, ssh-tunnel

I need to be able to access devices in certain LAN without being there. I thought VPN could help me with it, but I wasn't able to find anything for my situation. So if you could please point me in the right direction, or tell me what should I use.

**What I want:**
I have small LAN (made by basic TP-LINK home wifi router) with many RPi's doing stuff. If I want to SSH into them, I have to go there and connect my PC into this network.
What I would like to, is to be able to SSH into them no matter where I am. My dream (if its even possible) is to have virtual NIC, tunneled into this network, given IP from this network, so I could access devices in this LAN via the same IPs as I'm here. Once it's all set up, the user experience will be same for both cases, and you won't be able to tell, if you are physically connected to this LAN, or you are somewhere else. Is that even possible?

One big problem is that I can't have public IPv4 on this network (ISP said no). I should get IPv6, but it's not going to happend untill another year. But I have few VPS, all with public IPv4, that could be used to bridge this.

Main priority is to have this working from my Windows 10 PC. Having it work on Linux and Android is a nice to have,  but not a must.

**What I already tried:**
Having a SSH tunnel to one of my VPS. But this requires every RPi to be set up. Also, by default, I can't access all ports, I have to open another tunnel for every port I want. Biggest downside is that I have to remember which port goes where.

I thought VPN could be the right tool for this task, but based on what I could find, VPN server is used to access "outside internet" (to bypass geo location, have secured connection, etc). But I wan't to access LAN.

Could you please tell me what to look for/google or what should I use?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A VPN is indeed the tool for the job.  There are many twusts and ways this can be done.

I would get a low spec virtual server (eg minimal AWS EC2 instance) and set it up as an OpenVPN server, and enable routing/packet forwarding on it.  If the IOT/home network is in 192.168.1.0/24 I might set OpenVPN to allocate IP addresses from 172.16.0.0/24.

I would replace the firmware on the TPG router with DD-WRT, or if thats not possible (eg because it has a VDSL interface) put a second DD-WRT router between it and the LAN.

I would then set up an OpenVPN connections from my dd-wrt router to the VPN server, and another to my roaming laptop. Lastly I would have the VPN advertise the IOT/home routes to all clients, and ensure that this is routed to the home network.

In this way everything can see everything else on the network without NAT getting in the way.

As an aside, there are 2 modes for OpenVPN - Tun mode which is what I prefer and describe above, and TAP mode which I have not played arround with, but which will provide a more seemless experience if it works - by bridging 2 remote LANs together. While the latter appears closer to your udeal it is slower and harder to debug.